# Why are these pthreads segmentation faults possible?

Tags: php, multithreading, reference, segmentation-fault, pthreads

In [this introduction to pthreads](https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/6437782) I read that:

> When the programmer calls Thread::start, a new thread is created, a PHP interpreter context is initialized and then (safely) manipulated to mirror the context that made the call to ::start.

And later in the text the *segmentation fault* problem is addressed. This example of a segmentation fault is given:

```
class W extends Worker {
    public function run(){}
}
class S extends Stackable {
    public function run(){}
}
/* 1 */
$w = new W();
/* 2 */
$j = array(
    new S(), new S(), new S()
);
/* 3 */
foreach ($j as $job)
    $w->stack($job);
/* 4 */
$j = array();
$w->start();
$w->shutdown();
```

> The above example will always segfault; steps 1-3 are perfectly normal, but before the Worker is started the stacked objects are deleted, resulting in a segfault when the Worker is allowed to start.

**The questions are:**

1. Is the whole context that starts the new thread copied into the new thread when `start()` is called, or only at the time the interpreter sees a reference to a variable of the old context? In other words, is it enough to keep refcounts > 0 until `start()` is called?
2. Shouldn't references to the `Stackable` array enties be stored inside the `Worker` object so that the refcount of them after overwriting `$j` is still 1 and no segfault could occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The whole context is copied when the thread is started. You have to keep refcounts > 0 until the stacked objects are actually executed by the worker thread.

2) The reference counting built into variables in PHP was never prepared for multi-threading, many api functions decrement and increment refcounts and there is no opportunity to synchronize (lock). For that reason, you are responsible for maintaining a reference to any object that is destined to be executed by another thread.

These rather annoying, but unavoidable, facts can be side stepped by using the `Pool` abstraction provided with pthreads. It maintains references for you in the proper way.

http://php.net/Pool